# PUT command in xwiki

Tags: api, rest, put, xwiki

i'm trying to change the content of a page in xwiki with a put command .
in the rest API documentation of wiki:

> ```
> HTTP Method: PUT
>      Accepted Media types:
>         application/xml (Page element)
>         text/plain (Only page content)
>         application/x-www-form-urlencoded (allowed field names: title, parent, content)
>      Media types:
>         application/xml (Page element)
>      Description: Create or updates a page.
>      Status codes:
>         201: If the page was created.
>         202: If the page was updated.
>         304: If the page was not modified.
>         401: If the user is not authorized.
> ```

i tried something like that :

```
$ curl -X PUT -text/plain -T"C:\Users\braimm\Desktop\text.txt" \
"http://localhost:8082/xwiki/rest/wikis/xwiki/spaces/Sandbox/pages/TestPage1/"
```

but it doesn't work, it seems that i have to specify the media types, does anyone try to do something like that, i want just to change the content of a page with a PUT command.
thanks

Comment: actually the command that i did is $ curl -X PUT -T"C:\Users\braim\Desktop\text.txt" "http://localhost:8082/xwiki/rest/wikis/xwiki/spaces/Sandbox/pages/TestPage1"

Comment: i did it with that $ curl -u user:password -X PUT -T "@content" -H
 "Content-Type: text/plain" http://localhost:8080/xwiki/rest/wikis/xwiki/spaces
/Sandbox/pages/{PageName] this one change the content o a page in wiki

Comment: Did adding the `-H "Content-Type: text/plain"` solve the problem for you? (It should.) If yes, feel free to post this as an answer instead of a comment. This is actually encouraged, so people can better see the solution to the problem.

Answer (score 1):

i did it with that:

```
$ curl -u user:password -X PUT -T "@content" -H "Content-Type: text/plain" \
       localhost:8080/xwiki/rest/wikis/xwiki/spaces/Sandbox/pages/{PageName}
```

this one change the content of a page in wiki